# Class isn't recognized

Tags: java, class, compilation

I created a method class that will test the months and days and tell you what the season is. I'm creating a tester class but for some reason it won't recognize the `getSeason()` class from the methods but it shows they are connected.

Method Code:

```
public class Season {
    private String season;

    public String getSeason(int month, int day) {
        if (month == 1 || month == 2 || month == 3) {
            season = "Winter";
        } else if (month == 4 || month == 5 || month == 6) {
            season = "Spring";
        } else if (month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 9) {
            season = "Summer";
        } else if (month == 10 || month == 11 || month == 12) {
            season = "Fall";
        }

        if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {
            if (season.equals("Winter")) {
                season = "Spring";
            } else if (season.equals("Spring")) {
                season = "Summer";
            } else if (season.equals("Summer")) {
                season = "Fall";
            } else {
                season = "Winter";
            }
        }
        return season;
    }
}
```

Tester Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeasonTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Season s = new getSeason();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

I get a *cannot get symbol - class getSeason* error when I compile

Comment: Please follow a basic tutorial explaining how to work with objects and how to invoke methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a method instead of constructor here:

```
    Season s = new getSeason();
```

should be

```
    Season s = new Season();
```

Then you can call isntance method using this:

```
s.getSeason();
```

Comment: I'm very new at Java, this did it. Thanks!